# cin.ignore(), cin.ignore(1, '\n') and scanf("\n")

Tags: c++, class, oop, scanf, cin

I have this assignment. If I use `cin.ignore()`, the result is false, and `cin.ignore(1, '\n')` and `scanf("\n")`, the result is true.  I don't know why I fail. Please, help me

This assignment:

> Write a program to declare a class SinhVien (Student) with the following information: Student ID, Full name, Class, and GPA (float). The constructor has no parameters, and assigns the default values (empty string, 0) to the attributes.
>
> The program must use the stream operators to input and output student objects with cin and cout.
>
> The program must read the information of N students from the keyboard (without student ID). Then, the program must sort the students by GPA in descending order and print out the list of students on the screen, one line per student.
>
> In the case of Student ID, it is automatically generated according to the rule of adding the code B20DCCN followed by the automatically increasing integer value from 001 (maximum is 099). Full name is processed to bring it to the standard form. Date of birth is normalized to the form dd/mm/yyyy
>
> Input:
>
> The first line contains the number of students N (0 < N < 50).
>
> Each student is recorded on 4 lines, respectively for Full name, Class, Date of birth, and GPA.
>
> In which:
>
> Full name is not more than 30 characters.
> Class is in the correct format usually used at PTIT
> Date of birth has enough 3 parts of day, month, and year but may not be in the correct format dd/mm/yyyy.
> GPA is guaranteed to be within the 4-point scale with 2 at most 2 digits after the decimal point.
> The data ensures that no two students have the same GPA.
>
> Output:
>
> Print out the list of students with full Student ID, Full name, Class, Date of birth (normalized), GPA (with 2 digits after the decimal point) that have been sorted by GPA in descending order.

And my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

std::string so(int k)
{
    std::string st = std::to_string(k);
    if (st.length() == 1)
        st = "0" + st;
    return st;
}

class SinhVien
{
private:
public:
    static int dem;
    float gpa;
    std::string code, name, grade, date;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, SinhVien &object)
    {
        object.code = "B20DCCN0" + so(++dem);
        // input.ignore();
        input.ignore(1, '\n');
        /*         if (dem == 1)
                    scanf("\n");
                else input.ignore(); */

        auto formatName = [](std::string &st)
        {
            std::stringstream sst(st);
            std::string temp;
            st = "";
            while (sst >> temp)
            {
                for (char &c : temp)
                    if (isupper(c))
                        c = tolower(c);
                temp[0] = toupper(temp[0]);
                st += temp + " ";
            }
            st.pop_back();
        };

        std::getline(input, object.name);
        formatName(object.name);
        std::getline(input, object.grade);

        auto formatDate = [](std::string &st)
        {
            if (st[2] != '/')
                st = "0" + st;
            if (st[5] != '/')
                st.insert(3, "0");
        };
        std::getline(input, object.date);
        formatDate(object.date);
        input >> object.gpa;
        return input;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, SinhVien object)
    {
        output << object.code << " " << object.name << " " << object.grade << " " << object.date << " " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << object.gpa << std::endl;
        return output;
    }
};

int SinhVien::dem = 0;

void sapxep(SinhVien a[], int n)
{
    auto compare = [](SinhVien a, SinhVien b) -> bool
    {
        return a.gpa > b.gpa;
    };
    std::sort(a, a + n, compare);
}

int main()
{
    SinhVien ds[50];
    int N, i;
    cin >> N;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> ds[i];
    }
    sapxep(ds, N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << ds[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `cin.ingore()`, my program is RTE (Runtime Error)

Comment: What is the input you are using to test? What is the expected output?

Comment: Think about this. Why should the first thing that your `operator>>` does be to ignore a character? Why should a routine that is suppose to be reading something instead be ignoring the input whatever it is? This isn't a simple fix, it's a case of badly designed code.

Comment: I think the best advice is not to write code that uses a mix of `getline` and `operator>>` that often leads to trouble. Rewrite your reading code so that it only uses `getline` or only uses `operator>>`.

Comment: That's too much assignment and too much code for a Stack Overflow question. You've already experimented to determine which line of code (`cin.ignore`) triggers your error. That's the hard step. The next step is to determine which lines of code do **not** trigger your error. If there is a line of code that you can remove while still getting your RTE, then remove it. Don't worry about your assignment; focus on this error. Remove everything not required to reproduce the error (a.k.a make a [mre]).

Comment: You don't need any `ignore` to implement your assignment. Every `operator<<` implementation should start with a `getline`. Continue doing `getline` while the line is empty. Then when you get a non-empty line, parse it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're using `ignore` to begin with. Without a count, it will skip to the next `\n`, regardless of how many characters that it. With the count, it will skip at most than many characters. So after a `std::getline` (which removes the `'\n'` from the stream_), it will skip the next line completely without a count, and will skip the initial character of the line with a count. (The `scanf` variant will skip the next character if it is a `'\n'`, and set an error state otherwise.) You might want to skip initial white space in general (`input >> ws`) -- this will extract nothing if the next character in the stream is not a white space (which includes `'\n'`), but as the input is line oriented, I'd go with the suggestion of others here: use `std::getline` exclusively to extract data from the file, and the parse each line.

Also, you really should check the state of the stream after each `std::getline`, to make sure it has worked.

Comment: input has a number n representation  tests number
example:
2
ngUYen Van NaM
D20DCCN01-B
2/12/2002
2.17
Nguyen QuanG hAi
D20DCCN02-B
1/9/2002
3.0

Comment: @Bắc I know. I read the question. Given the format of the file, I'd still probably go with `std::getline`, then parse the line to get the number (since you want to read a complete line before starting to parse the individual records. Alternatively, you could read the number, then use `input.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' )` (or just `std::getline` into a throw-away string) to position the input at the start of the next line.